# Android GridView hides my Buttons

Tags: android-layout

I have a LinearLayout in my android application.

Worked well with just the two Buttons - but when I added the GridView, it now hides the two Buttons - regardless if I put them above or below the GridView

Can anyone help ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numColumns="4"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"/>

<Button android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/week" />
<Button android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/day" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this - it was because the root level LinearLayout was set with an orientation of horizontal.

I changed this to 'vertical' and then wrapped the two Button elements in their own LinearLayout with 'horizontal' orientation - all works as I needed now.

Here is the resulting XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

        <Button android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/week" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/day" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: The blockquotes keep hiding sections of the XML doc. The Xml above has a root level LinearLayout missing with orientation set to 'vertical'.